# negative values are being treated as positive in RHEL suddenly. Why?

Tags: test, math

For example:

```
# [[ -24 > 0 ]] &&  echo "Hi"
Hi
```

Since yesterday, I found this weird behavior. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because "-24" is greater than "0" on a string comparison basis - three characters versus one character. For comparing numbers:

```
$ [[ -24 -gt 0 ]] && echo "Hi"
$
```

Comment: Thanks @John..changing to gt fixed the issue. I wonder why we faced this issue only now. There was recently a migration. So, something might have been changed. And as I understood, only == sign works with numbers too right?

Comment: `man bash` will explain the different tests (go to the CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS section).  In this case it says that `==` is for _strings_.    The `-eq` operator is used for arithmetic comparison.

Comment: man test will give you a more explicit answer for the test operators